# Replace text (with question mark) using regex

Tags: regex, replace

I want to replace a text which contains "?" character using regex.

var test = "{=countAreas?area=123}";

I want to replace it with:

"{=countAreas?area=123}X"

I tried below code but "?" character creates an issue since it's a part of regex's identifiers:

test.replace(new RegExp(arrMatch[i], 'g'), "" + arrMatch[i] + "X");

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/494122/3832970).

Comment: The link does not explain how to escape '?'

Comment: It does. Use `RegExp.quote = function(str) {
     return str.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
 };` and then `var result = test.replace(RegExp(RegExp.quote(arrMatch[i]), "g"), "" + arrMatch[i].replace(/\$/g, "$$$$") + "X");`

Comment: ok, just got that. Thanks for reverting